# Проблемы с роутингом JS

Tags: javascript, веб-программирование, маршрутизация, spa

Организовал простой "динамический" роутинг на странице, все работает вроде ок, но когда перезагружается страница для которой реализованная эта динамика, пропадают все скрипты и выдает следующую ошибку: ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found), мучаюсь уже часа 2 ничего придумать не могу.
Код роутинга:

```
const navigateTo = url => {
    window.history.pushState(null, null, url);
    router();
}


const getParams = match => {
    const values = match.result.slice(1);
    const keys = Array.from(match.route.path.matchAll(/:(\w+)/g)).map(result => result[1]);

    return Object.fromEntries(keys.map((key, i) => {
        return [key, values[i]];
    }));
};

const routeQuestionID = path => new RegExp("^" + path.replace(/\//g, "\\/").replace(/:\w+/g, "(.+)") + "$")

const router = async () => {
    const routes = [
        { path: "/questions", view: ListOfQuestions},
        { path: "/questions/:id", view: Question},
    ];

    const potentialMatches = routes.map(route => {
        return {
            route, 
            result: location.pathname.match(routeQuestionID(route.path))
        }
    })

    let match = potentialMatches.find(potentialMatches => potentialMatches.result !== null);

    if(!match) match = {
        route: routes[0],
        result: [location.pathname],
    }
    
    //Create routing component
    const instance = new match.route.view(getParams(match));
    await instance.renderComponent();
};
```

Comment: Очень похоже, что у вас какой-то ajax запрос, например из какой то view. Или возможно сервер отдаёт 404 если не настроен редирект

Comment: Как минимум в двух местах некорректная обработка урла, или надо дальше велосипедить, или возьми обкатанный вариант и займись более полезными делами - https://github.com/visionmedia/page.js